# free-jQgrid "loading" message still remains

Tags: jqgrid, loading, free-jqgrid

Since my app is online for to be tested by customer, I often meet this problem and I have to click several times on "Tiers" menu to hope it will disappear and give hand.

Here is a snapshot of the trouble :
[image]

WHen I use my app on local server (wampserver) I never meet this trouble.

I have several grids in my app and none displays this message online.

Firebug says "jquery.jqgrid.min.js" has error in line 344 (?). Used version is 4.13.5-pre dated 2016-08-27 and hosted server runs with php 5.6.8

Does somebody already met this type of trouble ?

If somebody can take some time to help me, I can give by email login and pass to test app online.

Many thanks for your kind help.

Cheers
JiheL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting the issue. It would be helpful if you report the error using `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`, but I suppose that the only place in the code, which could produce the error is the piece of code with `if ($input[0].tagName.toUpperCase() === "SELECT" && $input[0].multiple) {...` (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.custom.js#L959)).

I posted [the fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/e99121f067a1b6670b9b9f1f9a6ac23ee695d5e6) just now, which should eliminate the error. It includes the additional test `if ($input.length > 0) {...}` (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.custom.js#L958)). I would still recommend you to examine the `name` and `index` values in `colModel` of your grids. It seems that your current code uses the filter with names or index, which is *not* from `colModel` or which uses some special characters. It's the only reason of the error, which one can see in console of your picture.

Comment: Many thanks Oleg for your kind help. As usually you're the master ! I have verified filter names (no indexes) I don't find any special characters but after inserting the new line in jqgrid code, the mistake doesn't appear now. Again many thanks. Have a nice day. Cheers JiheL

Comment: @JiheL: You are welcome! Your comment sounds that the problem is solved now. In the case it's good to "accept" the answer and to "close" the issue in the way.